# Dropbox works but no icon shows in the panel

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

I installed Dropbox on Xubuntu 14.04 using the package provided by Dropbox on its download web page.

Now, Dropbox works, but its icon does not show in the panel at startup, and I have to run `dropbox stop && dropbox start` in a terminal in order to get it.

I read that a simple workaround is to install package `nautilus-dropbox` via `apt-get`.

There are 2 issues:

1. I don't know how to uninstall Dropbox safely, without messing anything up.
2. My Dropbox folder is already synced on my PC. Once I install `nautilus-dropbox`, I'd like to make it read this folder without resyncing all that stuff. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Did the site say to uninstall dropbox and install `nautilus-dropbox`? Or just install `nautilus-dropbox`? Maybe you don't need to uninstall. Anyway;

1. This command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove dropbox
   ```

   will remove it safely.
2. Copy your dropbox folder somewhere else, say your Documents folder, then copy it back. It shouldn't need to sync again.

Comment: This doesn't work. My dropbox was not installed via apt-get, so it cannot uninstall dropbox..

Comment: What about synaptic package manager? You should be able to even if it wasn't.

Comment: Weel I installed synaptic. Dropbox is marked as not installed, unfortunately..